# Rels not updated when inserting image into Word template using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, .net-7.0

I'm trying to insert an image into a Word template document using Open XML SDK and while the actual 'insertion' of the `Drawing` element works, the document's *.rels* never get updated and thus the image cannot be displayed in the resulting document.

Code part opening the template and create a copy for editing

```
MemoryStream documentStream;
await using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(templateFile.PhysicalPath
                                               ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(templateFile.PhysicalPath))))
{
    documentStream = new MemoryStream((int)stream.Length);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(documentStream, cancellationToken);
    documentStream.Position = 0L;
}

using var template = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentStream, true, new OpenSettings {
    AutoSave = true
});
template.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

// add bitmaps to doc, see below...

template.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
template.Save();

return documentStream.ToArray();
```

Code part adding image part (from bitmap), add drawing to cell

```
var imageName       = $"I{index:X}";
var imagePart       = template.MainDocumentPart!.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg, imageName);

using var qrCodeStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(qrCodeStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

imagePart.FeedData(qrCodeStream);

var element = GetDrawingElement(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, imageName, imagePartId);
tableCell.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
```

Code part creating the drawing element

```
const double englishMetricUnitsPerInch = 914400;
const double pixelsPerInch = 96;

var emuWidth = width * englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;
var emuHeight = height * englishMetricUnitsPerInch / pixelsPerInch;

return new Drawing(
    new DrawingWordprocessing.Inline(
        new DrawingWordprocessing.Extent { Cx = (Int64Value?)emuWidth, Cy = (Int64Value?)emuHeight },
        new DrawingWordprocessing.EffectExtent
        {
            LeftEdge = 0L,
            TopEdge = 0L,
            RightEdge = 0L,
            BottomEdge = 0L
        },
        new DrawingWordprocessing.DocProperties
        {
            Id = GetRandomId(),
            Name = imageName
        },
        new DrawingWordprocessing.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
            new GraphicFrameLocks { NoChangeAspect = true }),
        new Graphic(
            new GraphicData(
                    new Picture(
                        new NonVisualPictureProperties(
                            new NonVisualDrawingProperties
                            {
                                Id      = GetRandomId(),
                                Name    = imageName
                            },
                            new NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                        new BlipFill(
                            new Blip(
                                new BlipExtensionList(
                                    new BlipExtension
                                    {
                                        Uri = "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                    })
                            )
                            {
                                Embed = imagePartId,
                                CompressionState =
                                    BlipCompressionValues.Print
                            },
                            new Stretch(
                                new FillRectangle())),
                        new ShapeProperties(
                            new Transform2D(
                                new Offset { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                new Extents { Cx = (Int64Value?)emuWidth, Cy = (Int64Value?)emuHeight }),
                            new PresetGeometry(
                                    new AdjustValueList()
                                )
                                { Preset = ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                )
                { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
    )
    {
        DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
        DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
        DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
        DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U,
        EditId = "50D07946"
    });
```

I've ensured:

- The document gets properly closed and disposed
- That all id's are unique
- The generated XML code is valid
- Compared my code to a generated reference code from a valid document using Open XML Productivity Toolkit

What am I missing here? Other questions indicate that I need to 'Close' the document, however in the current version of Open XML SDK this method doesn't exist anymore and disposing should take care of it.